# Reading a json object in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, json, forms, codeigniter

Im trying to use a controller function to read a JSON object sent by ajax, but im not able to read the JSON in php.

This is the jquery script. I've tried setting the

```
 $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('#contact-form').on('submit', function () {

            var form = $(this),
                url = "<?php echo site_url('home_controller/processContactForm'); ?>",
                method = form.attr('method'),
                data = {},

            form.find('[name]').each(function(index,name){
                var input = $(this),
                    name = input.attr('name'),
                    value = input.val();

                    data[name] = value; // Looping through each input inside the form and adding the values to the data Object
                )};

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: method,
                    data: data,
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

And this is the controller function :

```
public function processContactForm()
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Var dump is printing *null*

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($_POST['data']);` to see if you are even getting a correct value to pass to `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function processContactForm()
{
    if(isset($_POST['data'] && $_POST['data'] != NULL) {
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($data);
        echo '</pre>';
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: it outputs nothing because is giving null.

Comment: The problem was caused by a misconfiguration in the php.ini file, the post_max_size was set to 8MB instead of 8M.

post_max_size = 8MB (before)
post_max_size = 8M (after)

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax function to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: { data: data }, // create an object with a property of "data"
    success:function(response){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The `data` property in the `ajax` settings object will turn the keys (property names) of the data array/object into the `$_POST` keys.